# Gradle TaskOutputs.upToDateWhen timing out?

Tags: gradle

I just tweaked my Gradle build to add an upToDateWhen closure which examines the lastModified time of a bunch of the tasks output files. (It's a scan of roughly 200-300 files). It runs just fine locally but when I pushed it to my Jenkins build server (which runs a lot slower than my local machine) the closure appeared to return true but the task still ran. I saw this in the output:

```
myTask task is 0 days old...
Executing task ':myTask' (up-to-date check took 0.092 secs) due to:
  No history is available.
```

followed immediately by output that is generated when the task is run. The 1st line is a println I stuck in the upToDateWhen closure to help me see what it evaluates to. Basically if the latest modified file is less than 1 day old I consider the task up to date. The zero means it should be returning true. (I just updated the build to print the return value and will try to run it in a few.) While I initially thought it was just returning the wrong value I double checked and noticed the ABSENCE of this which shows in the output when run locally:

```
myTask task is 0 days old...
:myTask UP-TO-DATE
:myNextTask
```

So I'm questioning whether the upToDateWhen closure is being timed-out on the build server and defaulting to false. Is there such logic in Gradle to timeout an upToDateClosure and assume false if it takes too long or am I reading/wishing too much into this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is no timeout functionality in the upToDate when closure.

run your build with -i to get info logging enabled. This give's you more information why a task is considered up-to-date.